# Grep ignores whitespace

Tags: grep

I'm trying to search a large list of IP address for a particular IP, but am getting false positives because of spaces.  Please consider the following example:

```
$ a="192.168.1.1    192.168.1.2"
$ ip="1.1.192.168"

$ echo $a | grep "$ip"
192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2
```

Grep ignores the space and returns wrong results.  How can I get grep to recognize that "1.1    192.168" is not equal to "1.1.192.168"?

Comment: grep does not ignore whitespace, `.` is a special grep operator which means "any character". Use `grep -Fw "$ip"` and go read grep's manpage.

Comment: Your command is returning anything that matches any of `192.168.1.2`. `1`, `2`, `6`, `8`, `9`, `192`, `168`, and `.` (any character) all have matches in the output from the `echo` command. If you just want it to return. If you want to look for that exact string, then as mosvy said, you need to use `grep -F` or `grep -w`.

Comment: No, it matches `1<any char>1<any char>192<any char>168` and `echo $a` contains `1.1 192.168`. The output of `echo $a` is different from `echo "$a"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get used to quoting your variables.
You don't find a match after

```
echo "$a" | grep "$ip"
```

This is not a general solution, next time there might be just one space between the IPs.
Use

```
ip="1[.]1[.]192[.]168"
```

Still problems, you might match `101.1.192.168`.
So try the -Fw options

i.e. `echo "$a" | grep -Fw "$ip"`

Comment: @NasirRiley saying the same wrong thing twice doesn't make it right

Comment: @WalterA That is correct. $a absolutely does need to be quoted and I wasn't suggesting that it doesn't. I was referring to $ip, as you correctly surmised.

Comment: Yes I agree, quotes on the `$ip` don't matter. Were you suggesting removing them. Why? I am going to tidy this comment thread, as it is confusing and as we now see pointless.

Comment: Above was a discussion that is solved now. I have deleted my comments, trying to keep only relevant comments.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I wasn't suggesting removing them but was only stating that they weren't needed. I have deleted my previous comments and just left the last one so that it is clear that I was stating that `$ip` doesn't need to be quoted and not `$a`..